# Ownership Question

Tags: transactions, wallet, ownership

I have a very un-tech savvy friend who thinks she purchased $100 worth of bitcoin in 2008 or 2009, but has since relocated to another state and doesn't know where her records are. Is there some sort of database or transaction history that could be addressed/reviewed to see if this purchase did in fact occur?

Comment: 1. Bitcoin didn't exist in 2008, and i don't think there was a bitcoin exchange in 2009, so i don't see how someone who's not tech savvy could have ever find a way to buy it...                                                                                                         Your story seems extremely unlikely

Comment: this question doesn't seem realistic. Relocation adds nothing, the friend itself adds nothing, records (of what type?) add nothing, and database or transaction histories are stored on a PC or in the wallet software. Without more details it is impossible to be really helpful.

Comment: There are probably thousands of transactions for that amount, and besides, tracking down the transaction won't help you much. What you really need to know is where the bitcoins were puchased from, and whether they were left on an e-wallet (in which case you need login details) or stored in a locally installed wallet/paper wallet (in which case you need a wallet seed, private key, or wallet file).

Answer (score 1):

Your friend will need to remember the following things:

1. What computer she had the bitcoin wallet on.
2. The password for the
       wallet (assuming one was set)

If your friend only has the address, your friend will need the private key associated to it.

There is nothing you can really check/see if she bought bitcoins unless she either remembers her address in which case you can check the balance of, or finds the computer and wallet she used to store them in.